# Stuck in loop while code has been properly executed

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have written the following code to clear the dataset of duplicates if it meets a certain criteria (column E). It scans through 1216 lines of data (LastRow has 1216 hits) and clears the duplicates. Only issue I had was if I had two or three duplicates it would only delete one duplicate.

I wrote another line of code stating if a single item (column B) is found more than once that a variable called statement is equal to TRUE. So I want the loop to continue until no duplicates are present in the dataset, which will also turn the variable to FALSE and stop the loop. However, the loop continues endlessly. When I stop the script manually it seems to have cleared all the duplicates.

```
Sub ClearDataSet()

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rng, cell As Range
Dim Statement As Boolean

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

Set Rng = ws1.Range(("D1"), ws1.Range("D1").End(xlDown))
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort _
  key1:=ws1.Range("D1"), order1:=xlAscending, _
  Key2:=ws1.Range("E1"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Do

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If ws1.Cells(i, "D") = ws1.Cells(i + 1, "D") And _
          (ws1.Cells(i, "E") < ws1.Cells(i + 1, "E") Or _
          ws1.Cells(i, "E") = ws1.Cells(i + 1, "E")) Then

            Rows(i).Delete
        End If

   Next i

   For Each cell In Rng
       If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cell.Value) > 1 Then
           Statement = True
       End If
   Next cell

Loop Until Statement <> True

End Sub
```

**EDIT: Tweaked (and more efficient) script after solution of M Schalk**

```
Sub ClearDataSet()

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rng, cell As Range
Dim Statement As Boolean

Dim StartTime As Long
Dim TimeElapsed As Long

StartTime = Timer

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

Set Rng = ws1.Range(("D1"), ws1.Range("D1").End(xlDown))
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort _
  key1:=ws1.Range("D1"), order1:=xlAscending, _
  Key2:=ws1.Range("E1"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

For i = 2 To LastRow

    If ws1.Cells(i, "D").Value = "" Then
        GoTo OverStepcode
    ElseIf _
      ws1.Cells(i, "D") = ws1.Cells(i + 1, "D") And _
      (ws1.Cells(i, "E") < ws1.Cells(i + 1, "E") Or _
      ws1.Cells(i, "E") = ws1.Cells(i + 1, "E")) Then

        Rows(i).Delete
        i = i - 1
    End If

Next i

OverStepcode:

TimeElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime)
MsgBox "The code ran successfully in " & TimeElapsed & " seconds vbinformation"

End Sub
```

Comment: I added a more lightweight and easy to read solution for what you're trying to achieve to my solution, you should give that a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere inside the loop do you set `statement` to `False`. Therefore the loop end condition will never be fulfilled. If I understand your goal correctly you should add it here:

```
    If ws1.Cells(i, "D") = ws1.Cells(i + 1, "D") And _
        (ws1.Cells(i, "E") < ws1.Cells(i + 1, "E") Or ws1.Cells(i, "E") = ws1.Cells(i + 1, "E")) Then
         Rows(i).Delete
         statement = False
    End If
```

Also, `Loop Until Statement <> True` is the same as `Loop Until Statement = False`, which I find a bit easier to read.

On a separate note, this seems like an overly complicated approach, have you tried using `Remove Duplicates`?

As another more lightweight solution you could  remove the whole `statement` thing and simply add `i = i - 1` after finding a duplicate. This makes sure that you catch multiple duplicates of the same value and you don't need the whole `Do ... Loop` part. Try this modified version.

```
For i = 2 To LastRow

    If ws1.Cells(i, "D") = ws1.Cells(i + 1, "D") And _
        (ws1.Cells(i, "E") < ws1.Cells(i + 1, "E") Or ws1.Cells(i, "E") = ws1.Cells(i + 1, "E")) Then
         Rows(i).Delete
         i = i - 1
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to work! I was under the assumption that the statement variabel would automatically go to FALSE since it is a boolean. I even tested the code and it showed FALSE in my locals screen. 

Concerning my complicated approach. The dataset contains different part numbers on different contracts with different end dates of the contract. I dont want the script to delete just any duplicate but the one with the latest date. This seemed to me the least complicated approach, also i'm still learning how to code properly ;)

Comment: Ah I see, you should still try the second solution I added to the end of my answer. This should achieve what you're looking for while being more efficient and easier to read. :)

Comment: Thanks, that is genius! Should have thought about such a solution. I tweaked my code abit (see edit in my orginal post). The i = i - 1 line also made it stuck in an endless loop though since the LastRow value kept being 1216 while 600 rows were deleted. So it kept being stuck at the last non empty row (575). I added a GoTo line of code to bypass this

Comment: Also code has being executed in 6 seconds (for 1200 rows)

Comment: Ah, you're right. You could also add `LastRow = LastRow - 1` after `.Delete` to bypass this problem.  Would keep the code relatively simple.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be there:

```
For Each cell In Rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cell.Value) > 1 Then
        Statement = True
    End If
Next cell
```

`Statement` gets set to `true`, if there are duplicates left. it needs to check, if there are none left and then set it to `false`

Comment: Thank you, the answer before you said kind of the same thing and i fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I see two things:

First: you do a `Do Until Statement<>True`. But in your code, there is nothing that changes the value of `Statement`. At first run of code, when VBA initializes de variable for the first time, yes, default value will be `False`, but then your code changes the value here:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cell.Value) > 1 Then
    Statement = True
End IF
```

So the condition is probably not being fulfilled.

**ADVICE:** When you use an `If ...then`, you can type everything in 1 single line if there is only one statement and there is no `Else` part. This means your code above could be resumed like this:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cell.Value) > 1 Then Statement = True
```

Second: This is just theory, I've not tested properly.

Your `For Each`, I think it may not working properly. You have this:

```
For Each cell In Rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cell.Value) > 1 Then
        Statement = True
    End If
Next cell
```

In code above, you are looping torugh **each** cell in `rng.` And before, you did `Set Rng = ws1.Range(("D1"), ws1.Range("D1").End(xlDown))`. But later on you delete rows, and you never updated `rng`. This means that, probably, there are several blank values in `rng`, because you assigned the range **before** deleting.

Because there are several blank values, `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cell.Value)` will return always more than 1, making `Statement=True` and creating an eternal loop.

Comment: That second point is a nice observation, I didn't even think of that. However, I just tested it and VBA automatically adjusts the `Range` if cells are deleted so it won't be a problem.

Comment: I also would have expected the behavior you described though.

Comment: Thank you for comment foxfire, i've tweaked the code after m.schalk his comment. It doesn't even include the set Rng lines anymore.